# Unable to create capped Collection mongdb

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to create capped collection in MongoDB using Java-Mongo driver:

```
  CreateCollectionOptions options = new CreateCollectionOptions();
  options.capped(true);
  options.sizeInBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE);
  options.maxDocuments(12);

  db.createCollection("timeStamp", options);
```

If I check in mongodb, I see that the collection is not capped.

```
  >db.timeStamp.isCapped()
   false
```

Am I missing something here? MongoDB version is 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long.MAX_VALUE is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

8 exbibyte (1 exbibyte = 2 to the power of 53 bytes).

So it is obvious now you just have create something based on your memory limitations.

I'm not entirely sure how did it not error out. Please verify if your collection ever got created.

Comment: Yes looks like this is the problem. If i set the size to some lesser value (lilke 1GB) it is working fine. But i had these settings with the intention only to have the maxDocument as constraint (not the size so thought of setting it to max)